# Evaluating the following integral: $ \iiint_S \sqrt{x^2/9+y^2/4+z^2} \, dV$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am calculating:

$$ \iiint\limits_S  \sqrt{\frac{x^2}9+\frac{y^2}4+z^2} \, dV$$

Where $S$ is the region over the $xy$ plane and inside the intersection of the ellipsoid  $\tfrac{x^2}9+\tfrac{y^2}4+z^2=1$ and the cone $\tfrac{x^2}9+\tfrac{y^2}4=z^2$.

To solve this, I tried using spherical coordinates; 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!r\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
y\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
z\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!r\cos{\phi}\end{array} $$

And got the following integral:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{1/(\sqrt{2}\sin{\phi})}^1  \frac{1}6 r^3\cos{\phi}\, dr\ d\phi \ d\theta$$

What happens is that this integral in not defined for $\phi=0$.  Maybe you could help me out with this.

**EDIT**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I actually used the coordinates:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!3r\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
y\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!3r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
z\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!r\cos{\phi}\end{array} $$

As the intersection happens at $z=1/\sqrt2$, so if you plug-in this value of $z$ in the equation of the ellipsoid you obtain $r=1/(\sqrt2 sin{\phi})$, and as $\tfrac{x^2}9+\tfrac{y^2}4+z^2=1$ you obtain that $r=1$. Using this two conditions I concluded that:
$$1/(\sqrt2 sin{\phi})<r<1$$

And similarly that:

$$0<\theta<2\pi$$ and $$0<\theta<\pi/4$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R = r\sin\phi$ and consider the change of variables:
\begin{align*}
x &= 3R\cos\theta \\
y &= 2R\sin\theta \\
z &= r\cos\phi
\end{align*}
Notice that:
$$
\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = R^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta) = R^2 \\
z^2 + R^2 = r^2(\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi) = r^2
$$
Hence, the ellipsoid is given by:
$$
r^2 = 1 \iff r = 1
$$
and the cone is given by:
$$
R^2 = z^2 \iff R = z \iff r\sin\phi = r\cos\phi \iff \tan\phi = 1 \iff \phi = \pi/4
$$
Now consider what happens when we slice the desired region at some fixed $\theta$ so that we are in the $Rz$-half-plane. Then our cross-section is defined by the vertical line $R = 0$, the quarter-circle $z = \sqrt{1 - R^2} \iff r = 1$, and the line $z = R \iff \phi = \pi/4$. So the bounds for our integral should be:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^1 \textsf{(stuff)} \, dr \, d\phi \, d\theta
$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try the change of variables $$\begin{array}{rcl}
x\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!\color{red}{3}r\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
y\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!\color{red}{2}r\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\\
z\!\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!r\cos{\phi}\end{array} $$
 and marvel at the result...

Comment: Oh! I actually did those, just wrote it wrong in the question. My problem is with the term $1/\sin{\phi}$

Comment: Show in detail how you arrive at integrals involving $1/\sin\phi$ (and please do not change the question after answers are posted, add to it instead).

Comment: How do I 'add' without editing?

Comment: You add lines at the end of the post, usually starting with "EDIT:" or something equivalent.

Comment: All right, just did it